# Reading this file rather than creating a new one?

Tags: java, arrays, string, file

So right now I'm making a "friend" system for a game called Minecraft. The issue is that when you restart, you have no friends! It creates a new file no matter what, rather than reading the previous one. Here's my code:

```
public static boolean friends = true;
public static List friend = new ArrayList();


public static void friendsList(){
    if(friends){
        try{
            File file = new File("friends.txt");
            BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            for(int i = 0; i < friend.size(); i++){
                bufferedwriter.write((new StringBuilder()).append((String) friend.get(i)).append("\r\n").toString());
            }
            bufferedwriter.close();
        }
        catch(Exception exception){
            System.err.print(exception.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is very important, but here's how you add friends(par1Str is the string you enter when you send a chat message):

```
if(par1Str.startsWith("&friendadd")){
        Camb.friends = true;
        String as0[] = par1Str.split(" ");
        Camb.friend.add(as0[1]);
        mc.thePlayer.addChatMessage("\2479[CAMB]\247e Added Friend.");
        Camb.friendsList();
        Camb.friends = false;
        return;
    }
```

How would I make it so if the file already exist, it will load from it rather than overwriting it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any code to read a friends file.

Comment: Check if the file exists, and read it in?

Comment: By calling [`file.exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) for starters. Aside: your `write()` call is funky, you know you don't need the StringBuilder, just do `bufferedWriter.write((String) friends.get(i)); bufferedWriter.write("\r\n");`. Or `+` the two together - the performance admonishment about concatenating `String`s with `+` is mostly BS - you'll probably never write a program where the difference matters.

Comment: Also you don't need `"\r\n"` if you don't need your file to be viewable in Notepad for some reason. "`\n`" will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the file with the list of friends at some point. You can then set a flag to avoid writing it out again.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to check if a file already exists.

```
File f = new File("friends.txt");

if(f.exists()){
    System.out.println("File exists"); 
    //Append to the end
} else{
    System.out.println("File not found!");
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm a little confused. How would I go about actually implementing this into my code?